# JavaScript, trying to make my game more OOPey, broke it

Tags: javascript, oop

Originally i used var playerPaddle1 = {...} and i got my pong game working, but i want to learn better OOP techniques so now i have:

```
function Paddle() {
    this.x = 50;
    this.y = 234;
    this.vx = 0;
    this.vy = 0;
    this.width = 19;
    this.height = 75;
    this.draw = function() { 
        var self = this;
        var img = new Image();  
        img.src = 'images/paddle.png';  
        img.onload = function(){  
            ctx.drawImage(img, self.x, self.y);  
        };
    };
    this.update = function() {
        // Divide velocity by FPS before adding it
        // onto the position.
        this.x += this.vx / FPS;
        this.y += this.vy / FPS;
         // Collision detection
        if ( (this.x) < 0 ) {
            this.x = 0;
        }
        /*if ( (this.x + this.width) > (canvas.width / 2) ) {
            this.x = (canvas.width / 2) - this.width;*/

        if ( (this.y) < 0 ) {
            this.y = 0;
        }
        if ( (this.y + this.height) > canvas.height) {
            this.y = canvas.height - this.height;
        }
    };
};

var player1Paddle = new Paddle();
```

And now my keyboardInput script does not work for the paddle anymore (my paddle will no longer move when i press the keys).

```
window.onkeydown = function( e ) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var code = e.keyCode;
    if ( code === 37 ) {
        player1Paddle.vx = -200;
    } else if ( code === 38 ) {
        player1Paddle.vy = -200;
    } else if ( code === 39 ) {
        player1Paddle.vx = 200;
    } else if ( code === 40 ) {
        player1Paddle.vy = 200;
    }
};

window.onkeyup = function( e ) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var code = e.keyCode;
    if ( code === 37 ) {
        player1Paddle.vx = 0;
    } else if ( code === 38 ) {
        player1Paddle.vy = 0;
    } else if ( code === 39 ) {
        player1Paddle.vx = 0;
    } else if ( code === 40 ) {
        player1Paddle.vy = 0;
    }
};
```

I thought i set it up exactly the same but with a constructor function instead of just a variable object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.onkeydown = function( e ) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var code = e.keyCode;
    if ( code === 37 ) {
        player1Paddle.vx = -200;
    } else if ( code === 38 ) {
        player1Paddle.vy = -200;
    } else if ( code === 39 ) {
        player1Paddle.vx = 200;
    } else if ( code === 40 ) {
        player1Paddle.vy = 200;
    }
    player1Paddle.update(); // you forget to tell it to do something with the new info!
    player1Paddle.draw();
};

window.onkeyup = function( e ) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var code = e.keyCode;
    if ( code === 37 ) {
        player1Paddle.vx = 0;
    } else if ( code === 38 ) {
        player1Paddle.vy = 0;
    } else if ( code === 39 ) {
        player1Paddle.vx = 0;
    } else if ( code === 40 ) {
        player1Paddle.vy = 0;
    }
    player1Paddle.update(); // you forget to tell it to do something with the new info!
    player1Paddle.draw();
};
```

Comment: Oh thanks but i never had draw() there because i have this:

// Game loop draw function
function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    ball.draw();
 player1Paddle.draw();
 //playerPaddle2.draw();
};

// Game loop update function
function update() {
    ball.wallDetect();
 ball.paddleDetect(player1Paddle);
 console.log(player1Paddle.x);
 //playerPaddle.update();
 //playerPaddle2.update();
};

function tick() {
    draw();
 update();
};

setInterval( tick, 1000 / FPS );

Comment: AANNDDD i see now by reading my above comment, that i had commented out "playerPaddle.update()" and it also had the wrong object name which is meant to be player1Paddle.update(). Silly me. Thanks, you made me see my mistake!

Comment: Yep i should have sorry. Tried to simplify it for everyone but it was important code.

Comment: HAHAHA... glad I could 'kinda' help

Comment: Stack overflow seems to think my reputation is too low to upvote. Psshh. I can delete the question if it is to tell people it is solved.

Comment: I think i did just now but i'm not savvy on this site.